# How to implement GestureDetector in reuseable class widget?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, reusability, code-reuse, gesturedetector

I am successfully able to make a reusable stateful widget and added text but don't know about how to make reusable gesture detector

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String collectionName;

  HomeScreen(this.collectionName);

  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}
```

---

```
Text(widget.collectionName)
```

How to use a gesture detector like **TEXT** ????

Comment: you want to pass a gesture as parameter to click that text? Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to do is add GestureDetector to your text and pass the function via HomeScreen. If that's what you are looking for then

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String collectionName;
  final VoidCallBack onTap;

  HomeScreen(this.collectionName,this.onTap);

  @override
 _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}
```

Your Text widget will be updated as

```
GestureDetector(
  onTap:widget.onTap,
  child:Text(widget.collectionName)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Example of how you can do this...

Make this..

```
Widget gestureDetectorforText(dynamic theText){
  return GestureDetector(
    onTap: your function here..
    child: Text(theText)
  );
 }
```

So using that code means that you need to pass your widget.collectionName into it..

So whenever you call the widget gestureDetector()

You pass the widget.collection name into it like this..

`gesturedetector(widget.collectionName);`